# Search in subarray

Tags: php, laravel

I have arrays which I get so

```
 $article_foundd = Article::all();
```

Array itself

```
"["meta_title"]=> string(5) "sport" 
 ["meta_description"]=> string(4) "NEWS" 
 ["meta_keyword"]=> string(7) "sport, olimp" 


"["meta_title"]=> string(7) "climate" 
 ["meta_description"]=> string(14) "Climate change" 
 ["meta_keyword"]=> string(19) "climate,weather,rain" 


"["meta_title"]=> string(7) "box"
 ["meta_description"]=> string(19) "box" 
 ["meta_keyword"]=> string(7) "sport,box,roy,tyson"
```

I need that when a person entered “sport” in the search bar, then all articles related to sports would be displayed, for example.
Search all by `meta_keywords`

At the moment I have implemented a meta title, but I need to use the keys.

```
$q = Input::get ( 'q' );
$article_found = Article::where('meta_title','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->get();
if(count($article_found) > 0)
    return view('blog.search')->withDetails($article_found)->with('details' =>$article_found);
```

Comment: I think this will work if your search items by one keyword name. Example `$article_found = Article::where('meta_keyword','LIKE', $q)->get();`

Comment: Do you mean you want to search the column called `meta_keywords` instead of the column you are currently searching which is `meta_title` ??

Comment: @AndreasHunter this is how it works, if only the key entered in the array comes first

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes

Comment: I've mistake in my query @СаскеУчиха. Your `meta_keyword` field type is `string` or `array`?

Comment: If string this must work `$article_found = Article::where('meta_keyword','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->get();` OR if array then `$article_found = Article::whereIn('meta_keyword', $q)->get();`

Comment: @AndreasHunter  as I understand that a string.
in your way, it displays to me only (from the example) the first three, and then it turns out, if I enter “sport”, then I need to output two entries, and it displays only one

Comment: @AndreasHunter I think it is just a comma delimited list.

Comment: @AndreasHunter  Thank you very much, everything works, I just didn’t fix it in the beginning. everything works. Write your decision in the answers so that I can mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example query for searching items by field `meta_keyword`

```
$article_found = Article::where('meta_keyword','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->get();
```